# Unrecognised database format E:\filename.accdb not found in MSACCESS 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

I had created one database with 6 tables and 6 forms. After creating the 6 forms and 6 tables , the access database filename.accdb is opening in only one system. If am sharing with another systems, the database is showing an error which is "Unrecognised database format E:\filename.accdb". . Please let my issue be resolved. After trying so many trials am posting my question here so that m problem regarding the database opening in another systems is resolved.I had tried compact and repair database, changing the filename and storing in another drive. Even though it is not opening in another any single system too.In all the systems its showing the same error except my system.

Comment: Can any one help me out how to change created databased from  microsoft access version 2010 to microsoft access version 2007

Answer (score 0):

Atlast i had found a solution to it. The database created version is Microsoft Access 2010. But when i dump database in to Microsoft Access 2007, its web compatibility is missing i hope. That's why i am getting an error always when am trying in 2007 version.

Comment: Yes exactly. Web compatibility is missing. Then i had made the changes like changing the version from 2010 msaccess.accdb to msaccess.mdb. But Calculation wizard is not working when i changed the version.